# Class method contains selector call to a method of another class

Tags: objective-c, class

So I created a class CommonMethods with class method:

```
+ (CCMenu *)createMenu:(NSString *)menuName atPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    CCMenuItemImage *menuBlock = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:menuName selectedImage:menuName target:self selector:@selector(choose:)];
    CCMenu *menuBlockMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuBlock, nil];
    menuBlockMenu.position = position;
    return menuBlockMenu;
}
```

Now in my MainClass which contains choose: method, I create a menu:

```
CCMenu *regularBlockMenu = [CommonMethods createMenu:kbRegularBlock atPosition:position];
[self addChild:regularBlockMenu];
```

My program crashes when I tap the menu because it doesn't understand selector call. How do I implement this? I want to create a CommonMethods method because I will use this method over and over in many classes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a method choose in class MainClass? if so, you need modify your createMenu function a bit. Try this,

```
+ (CCMenu *)createMenu:(NSString *)menuName atPosition:(CGPoint)position forTarget:(id)target 
{
    CCMenuItemImage *menuBlock = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:menuName selectedImage:menuName target:target selector:@selector(choose:)];
    CCMenu *menuBlockMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuBlock, nil];
    menuBlockMenu.position = position;
    return menuBlockMenu;
}
```

then in MainClass:

```
CCMenu *regularBlockMenu = [CommonMethods createMenu:kbRegularBlock atPosition:position forTarget:self];
[self addChild:regularBlockMenu];
```

and you need to define `-(void)choose:(id)sender;` in MainClass

So what this is doing is setting the target of choose: to be an instance of MainClass, rather than CommonMethods.

Answer (score 1):

Since `self` in a class method refers to the class, you should not be making `self` a target of your selector:

```
CCMenuItemImage *menuBlock = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:menuName selectedImage:menuName target:self selector:@selector(choose:)];
//                                                                                            HERE ------^^^^
```

Instead, you should be sending the selector to an object that responds to the selector `choose:`

Answer (score 0):

you need to make CommonMethods a singleton

```
@implementation CommonMethods
static CommonMethods* globalCommonMethods = nil;
+(CommonMethods*)gCommonMethods
{
    if( !globalCommonMethods ) globalCommonMethods = [[CommonMethods alloc] init];
    return globalCommonMethods;
}
-(CCMenu *)createMenu:(NSString *)menuName atPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    CCMenuItemImage *menuBlock = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:menuName selectedImage:menuName target:self selector:@selector(choose:)];
    CCMenu *menuBlockMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuBlock, nil];
    menuBlockMenu.position = position;
    return menuBlockMenu;
}

-(void)choose:(id)sender
{
    //do stuff
}
```

now when you need to access CommonMethods use [CommonMethods gCommonMethods]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `+(void)choose:(id)sender`, since `createMenu:atPosition:` is a class methods?

Comment: you cant use a class method as a selector. since the button is going to be calling something like [delegate choose:self]; which wont work if you define choose as a class method.

Comment: But then what instance of `CommonMethods` should you send as the target of the selector? If you pass `self`, it Obj-C would not find your `choose:` selector, because `self` is `CommonMethods`'s `Class` object.

Comment: CommonMethods also needs to be a singleton which you call your -(CCMenu*)createMenu function on

Comment: This makes sense: in this case, yes, he would need a method with a minus.

Comment: But I can't implement choose: inside CommonMethods. It is specific for MainClass only. This will work and call choose: of CommonMethods, NOT choose: of MainClass. Right? Thanks.